# Создание нового проекта Django

Tags: python, django

[image]

Пытаюсь разобраться с Django.
Читаю док-ю.

Пытаюсь создать новый проект. Делаю, как написано (вроде).
Что получается:
[image]

---

*Не исключено, что я дебил. Но все же очень прошу мне с этим разобраться наконец*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужно добавить путь (например, C:\Python27\Scripts;) в переменную окружения Path и перезагрузиться